# C++ code Compiles in eclipse but got error "undefined reference to" when building

Tags: c++, namespaces, dllexport

Here I got Two C++ projects: Project1 and Project2

In project2, I got a new class SQLiteWrapper.h like this

```
namespace zinc{ 
namespace sql {
    boost::shared_ptr<sqlite3> openDatabase(const std::string& dbPath) ZINC_EXPORT;
}
}
```

Here ZINC_EXPORT is macro of dllexport.

Now I would like to call function "openDatabase" in SQLiteWrapper.h from Project2 in Project1

in project1, I call:

```
zinc::sql::openDatabase("path");
```

eclipse does not complain and also if I press F3, it will go to project2/SQLiteWrapper.h/openDataBase() exactly.

but when I build project1, I got the error says "undefined reference to `zinc::sql::openDatabase(std::string const&)'"

what the problem it maybe? I just cannot figure it out.

the Project1 calls a lot of methods in Project2 and it works, not quite sure why the new function in new class just does not work
Thanks

Comment: This is a linking error.  `Project1` needs to have a linker reference to `Project2` in the project settings.

Comment: Sow the linking command. Consider using `make`.

Comment: @abiessu could you help to specify it more clear? Since the Project1 calls a lot of methods in Project2 and they all works, there should be already a linker referenct to Project2, not quite sure why the new function in new class just does not work

Comment: Each library must be referenced separately.  If your new class in `Project2` is in a separate library from the previous classes, it must be linked separately.  If the class hasn't been compiled within `Project2` yet, then it must be compiled prior to being linkable to any outside libraries.  If it isn't already in your project settings, you should make sure that building `Project2` is in the build steps of `Project1`.